# phpQuery не хочет искать элемент

Tags: php, парсер, phpquery

Я пишу парсер сайта на PHP и использую для этого phpQuery.
Проблема в том что когда я ищу класс processed на странице https://www.parimatch.kz/sport/tennis/itf-pary-khammamet, он возвращает пустую строку, а на самом деле должен возвращать элемент tbody class="processed"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мой код:

```
    $url = 'https://www.parimatch.kz/sport/tennis/itf-pary-khammamet';
    $val = curlIt($url);
    $html = phpQuery::newDocument($val);
    $pq = pq($html);
    $elems = $pq->find('.proceesed');
    var_dump($elems->html());
```

Выводит:
`string(0) ""`

Что я сделал не так покажите на ошибку?

Comment: поскольку с хттпс соединение сбрасывается, а без него сайт заблокирован РКН, то повангую и скажу, что ваша таблица с классом тянется аяксом и в исходной странице ее нет. Ткните правой кнопкой и просмотрите исходный код страницы, без инспектора

Comment: да, я только что посмотрел и походу страница генерируется js-ом, но даже если так, с помощью php можно ли как-то спарсить этот класс?

Comment: Смотрите в консоли браузера что возвращает XHR запрос. Может там JSON и ничего парсить и не надо

Comment: phpQuery не подойдет. PHP не браузер, обрабатывать скрипты не умеет. Решение: разбираться откуда тянется скрипт и нужны ли спец заголовки и куки.

Answer (score -1):

> $elems = $pq->find('.proceesed');

Вы не тот класс ищете. Нужно 'processed'.